# Line of best fit of marginsplot

Tags: graph, regression, stata, margins

I am attempting to create a marginsplot and adding a line of best fit for those plotted marginal values to show a trend, as the margins are plotted over year dummies. The marginsplot can be seen here, where the red line shows the result I am looking to obtain (but is just an estimating line I have drawn on): https://i.stack.imgur.com/6UhMS.jpg

A snapshot of my data (limited to just the variables relevant to this post) can be seen here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gf8eK.jpg

Any advice on how to achieve this fitted line on the marginsplot would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what sort of margins you want to plot and what the underlying model is, but here's some code to get you started:

```
sysuse auto, clear
reg price i.rep78 c.weight
eststo margins: margins rep78, post
// eststo margins: margins, dydx(rep78) post

/* store margins output as a variable */
local levels: colnames e(b)
gen margins = .
foreach j of local levels  {
    replace margins = _b[`j'] if `j'==1
}

/* run a regression on the output of margins */
reg margins c.rep78
eststo lfit: margins, over(rep78) post

/* plot both margins and linear approximation */
coefplot (margins) (lfit, recast(line) offset(0)), vertical xlabel(, alternate)

drop margins
```

This yields:

[image]

`coefplot` is from SSC.

---

Here's a solution to the question in the comments:

```
sysuse auto, clear
reg price c.mpg##i.rep78 c.weight
margins r.rep78, dydx(mpg) post
/* store interaction coefficients as a variable */
local levels: colnames e(b)
gen margins = .
foreach j of local levels  {
    replace margins = _b[`j'] if `j'==1
}
/* plot margins with added line */
marginsplot, addplot(lfit margins rep78) recast(scatter) legend(off)
```

Comment: Apologies for not posting my model! I thought I had, that's my mistake.

reg lgross c.lmovielikes##i.release_year lcastlikes lbudget imdb_score i.content_rating i.is_* , robust

I am looking to plot the margins or coefficients for c.movielikes#i.release_year with a line fit for these values overlayed on the same axis.

Comment: @ctahim See the addendum above.